# Another way to pass arguments in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-class

I have a typescript class and a method in it.
This method takes three arguments.

```
class MyClass {

 public static carStatus(name : string , color : string , isReady : boolean){
    let result = isReady ? 'is ready' : 'is not ready';
    return `${color} ${name} ${result}.`;
 }
}

let carStatus = MyClass.carStatus('pride' , 'white' , true);
console.log(carStatus);
```

I want to set the third argument `(isReady)` out of the brackets into the method.
And i know it can be done by this way:

```
class MyClass {

public static isReady : boolean;

  public static carStatus(name : string , color : string){
    let result = this.isReady ? 'is ready' : 'is not ready';
    return `${color} ${name} ${result}.`;
  }
}

MyClass.isReady = false;
let carStatus = MyClass.carStatus('pride' , 'white');
console.log(carStatus);
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "Better" always depends on the use case, the problem you want to solve. Reducing code to a single line is almost never the "better" way. But in your case: you shouldn't use static methods and fields here. Here you could drop the class and just use a script. Your class does not any value.

Comment: @Andreas_D Thanks for your advice.
Yes you are quite right. And of course, the code I wrote in the question is just a simple example, and I never use static methods and class to do that. So according to your comment I have edited the question text.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest approach would be to use a separate method to set the `isReady` value and a single `CarStatus` class with no static methods:

```
class CarStatus {
    private isReady: boolean;

    constructor(private name: string, private color: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public setReady() {
        this.isReady = true;
    }

    public getStatus(): string {
        let result = this.isReady ? 'is ready' : 'is not ready';
        return `${this.color} ${name} ${result}.`;
    }
}

let carStatus = new CarStatus("pride", "white");
carStatus.setReady();
console.log(carStatus.getStatus());
```

You could also use a fluent approach if you believe each of the concepts are not necessarily required or can be set in different times. Depending on the case, this could be an overkill, so just as an example:

```
class CarStatus {  
    constructor(private name: string, private color: string, private isReady: boolean) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.isReady = isReady;
    }

    public getStatus(): string {
        let result = this.isReady ? 'is ready' : 'is not ready';
        return `${this.color} ${name} ${result}.`;
    }
}

class CarStatusBuilder {
    private name: string;
    private color: string;
    private isReady: boolean;

    public SetReady(): CarStatusBuilder {
        return new CarStatusBuilder() { this.isReady = true};
    }

    public WithName(name: string): CarStatusBuilder {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public WithColor(color: string): CarStatusBuilder {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    public Build(): CarStatus{
        return new CarStatus(this.name, this.color, this.isReady);
    }
}

let carStatus = new CarStatusBuilder()
    .WithColor("white")
    .WithName("pride")
    .Build();
console.log(carStatus.getStatus());
```